# How to ask phonegap plugin permission on exact run time and not on app start?

Tags: android, phonegap

I am building an app with phonegap build. My app has some plugins as i list below. When i run the app, at start it asks for "record audio" and "modify or delete SD card contents. read the contents of your SD card".

How can I prevent asking this permissions at start and make it ask on exact run time?

```
`<plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="2.4.1" />`
`<plugin name="cordova-plugin-compat" spec="1.2.0" />`
`<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.3.3" />`
`<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" spec="4.3.1" />`
`<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" spec="1.6.1" />`
`<plugin name="cordova-plugin-media-capture" spec="1.4.3" />`
`<plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="2.4.3" />`
`<plugin name="cordova-plugin-globalization" spec="1.11.0"/>`
`<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="5.0.3"/>`
`<plugin name="cordova-plugin-android-permissions" spec="1.0.0" />`
`<preference name="permissions" value="none" />`
`<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />`
`<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true"/>`
`<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="1300" />`
`<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />`
`<preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />`
`<preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />`
`<preference name="SplashScreenBackgroundColor" value="#34495e" />`
`<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />`
`<preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="true"/>`
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my own answer. Phonegap build app asks permissions at start but when you upload it to google play, the app downloaded from play store asks permissions on runtime.